# Drawing segments (tangents) of fixed lengths preserving the aspect angles with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Context: I'm trying to display the gradients as fixed-length lines on a plot of gradient noise. Each "gradient" can be seen as a tangent on a given point. The issue is, even if I make sure the lines have the same length, the aspect ratio stretches them:

[image: gradient noise]

The complete code to generate this:

```py
from math import sqrt, floor, modf, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mix = lambda a, b, x: a*(1-x) + b*x
interpolant = lambda t: ((6*t - 15)*t + 10)*t*t*t
rng01 = lambda x: modf(sin(x) * 43758.5453123)[0]


def _gradient_noise(t):
    i = floor(t)
    f = t - i
    s0 = rng01(i)     * 2 - 1
    s1 = rng01(i + 1) * 2 - 1
    v0 = s0 * f;
    v1 = s1 * (f - 1);
    return mix(v0, v1, interpolant(f))


def _plot_noise(n, interp_npoints=100):
    xdata = [i/interp_npoints for i in range(n * interp_npoints)]
    gnoise = [_gradient_noise(x) for x in xdata]

    plt.plot(xdata, gnoise, label='gradient noise')
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.ylabel('amplitude')
    plt.grid(linestyle=':')
    plt.legend()

    for i in range(n + 1):
        a = rng01(i) * 2 - 1  # gradient slope
        norm = sqrt(1 + a**2)
        norm *= 4  # 1/4 length
        vnx, vny = 1/norm, a/norm
        x = (i-vnx/2, i+vnx/2)
        y = (-vny/2, vny/2)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _plot_noise(15)
```

The red-lines drawing is located in the for-loop.

`hypot(x[1]-x[0], y[1]-y[0])` gives me a constant `.25` for every vector, which corresponds to my target length (¼). Which means my segments are actually in the correct length for the given aspect. This can also be "verified" with `.set_aspect(1)`:

[image: gradient noise aspect=1]

I've tried several things, such as translating the coordinates into display coordinates (`plt.gca().transData.transform(...)`), scale them, then back again (`plt.gca().transData.inverted().transform(...)`), without success (as if the aspect was applied on top of the display coordinates). Doing that would probably also actually change the angles as well anyway.

So to sum up: I'm looking for a way to display lines with a fixed length (expressed in the x data coordinates system), and oriented (rotated) in the xy data coordinates system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: gradient noise]

Final code with proper aspect ratio and resize event handled:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

from math import hypot, floor, modf, sin

mix = lambda a, b, x: a*(1-x) + b*x
interpolant = lambda t: ((6*t - 15)*t + 10)*t*t*t
rng01 = lambda x: modf(sin(x) * 43758.5453123)[0]


def _gradient_noise(t):
    i = floor(t)
    f = t - i
    s0 = rng01(i)     * 2 - 1
    s1 = rng01(i + 1) * 2 - 1
    v0 = s0 * f;
    v1 = s1 * (f - 1);
    return mix(v0, v1, interpolant(f))


def _get_ar(ax):
    fs = ax.figure.get_size_inches()
    pos = ax.get_position(original=False)
    return 1 / (ax.get_data_ratio() * (fs[0] * pos.width) / (fs[1] * pos.height))


def _get_line_coords(aspect, i):
    dx, dy = 1, rng01(i) * 2 - 1  # gradient slope
    norm = hypot(dx, dy * aspect)
    vnx, vny = dx/norm, dy/norm
    x = (i-vnx/2, i+vnx/2)
    y = (-vny/2, vny/2)
    return x, y


def _plot_noise(n, interp_npoints=100):
    xdata = [i/interp_npoints for i in range(n * interp_npoints)]
    gnoise = [_gradient_noise(x) for x in xdata]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xdata, gnoise, label='gradient noise')
    ax.set_xlabel('t')
    ax.set_ylabel('amplitude')
    ax.grid(linestyle=':')
    ax.legend(loc=1)

    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()

    aspect = _get_ar(ax)
    resize_objects = []
    for i in range(n + 1):
        lx, ly = _get_line_coords(aspect, i)
        line = ax.plot(lx, ly, 'r-')[0]
        ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(i, 0), width=1, height=1/aspect, fill=False, linestyle=':')
        ax.add_patch(ellipse)
        resize_objects.append((line, ellipse))

    def _onresize(event):
        ar = _get_ar(ax)
        for i, (line, ellipse) in enumerate(resize_objects):
            ellipse.set_height(1 / ar)
            lx, ly = _get_line_coords(ar, i)
            line.set_xdata(lx)
            line.set_ydata(ly)

    ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', _onresize)

    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _plot_noise(10)
```

Some notes:

1. the same question was asked on matplotlib discourse, where jklymak provided the correct answer for the ratio computation: https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/drawing-segments-tangents-of-fixed-lengths-preserving-the-aspect-angles-with-matplotlib/21844/14
2. the `ax.get_{x,y}lim()` → `ax.set_{x,y}lim()` roundtrip seems necessary because the aspect is computed based on the initial axis, which changes when plotting the lines/ellipses
3. the resize events is not necessary in case of export

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Welcome to SO. What a well asked first question. It made me question my sanity for a hot second once I reproduced the plot and the math checked out...

However, you identified the core problem yourself: the issue is that in your code the length of the gradient lines is determined in data coordinates, when it should be dependent on the aspect ratio of the plot.

So, if you want the gradient lines to be of uniform length in display space then you need to rescale the either the `dx` or the `dy` component by the aspect ratio of the plot (or its inverse, respectively) when computing then norm:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from math import sqrt, floor

mix = lambda a, b, x: a*(1-x) + b*x
interpolant = lambda t: ((6*t - 15)*t + 10)*t*t*t
rng01 = lambda x: ((1103515245*x + 12345) % 2**32) / 2**32


def _gradient_noise(t):
    i = floor(t)
    f = t - i
    s0 = rng01(i)     * 2 - 1
    s1 = rng01(i + 1) * 2 - 1
    v0 = s0 * f;
    v1 = s1 * (f - 1);
    return mix(v0, v1, interpolant(f))


def _plot_noise(n, interp_npoints=100):
    xdata = [i/interp_npoints for i in range(n * interp_npoints)]
    gnoise = [_gradient_noise(x) for x in xdata]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xdata, gnoise, label='gradient noise')
    ax.set_xlabel('t')
    ax.set_ylabel('amplitude')
    ax.grid(linestyle=':')
    ax.legend(loc=1)

    x0, x1, y0, y1 = ax.axis()
    aspect = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)

    for i in range(n + 1):
        dy = rng01(i) * 2 - 1  # gradient slope
        dx = 1
        norm = sqrt(dx**2 + (dy / aspect)**2)
        # norm *= 4  # 1/4 length
        vnx, vny = dx/norm, dy/norm
        x = (i-vnx/2, i+vnx/2)
        y = (-vny/2, vny/2)
        ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _plot_noise(15)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; thing is, I actually tried that already but the aspect ratio is not reliable: try to add a `from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse;ax.add_patch(Ellipse(xy=(i, 0), width=1, height=aspect, fill=False))` at the end of the loop: you will realize that the window actually gets resized automatically, so the Ellipse expected to be a Circle isn't actually round (which means the segment aren't the same length).

Comment: For more context, I was actually suggested to use `ax.figure.get_size_inches()` and `ax.get_position(original=False)` to figure out the correct aspect (which of course isn't reliable either as soon as the window is resized manually, in which case I need to handle resize events)... But at least for exports and the first size it appears to be OK...